# Ruby/rails: saving a sample of has_many relationship to database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

Asking this question re: a student project I'm working on and I have tinkered for too long without being able to come up with a solution.

I have a class called Game, a game has many quotes. If I create a game `@game = Game.create` and then associate it with characters `@game.characters = [@character1, @character2]`. Because of my associations, I have access to all of the quotes of both characters with `@game.quotes` (hundreds of objects returned).

I'd like to be able to grab a sample of 10 of the quotes, something like `@game.ten_quotes` (an array of objects) will return a random sample of `@game.quotes`. I also want `@game.ten_quotes` to be saved to the database.

My first thought is that I need a new attribute for Game in the migration:

```ruby
class CreateGames < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :games do |t|
        t.text :state, default: "[]"
        t.boolean :completed, default: false
        t.something :ten_quotes
        # what would this look like if I'm saving an array of objects?
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

In my rails controller below I was able to generate the ten quotes but I feel that I'm working in the wrong direction:

```ruby
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :game_logs
  has_many :characters, through: :game_logs
  has_many :quotes, through: :characters

  def generate_quotes
    if self.ten_quotes == []
      x = quotes.shuffle.sample(10)
      self.ten_quotes = x
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

How can I get a sample of quotes, associate that sample with a game instance and then save the game instance to the database one time with no chance to overwrite in the future? Do I need a new model?

Thanks in advance if you'd like to assist. Otherwise, have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class AddTenQuotesIdsColumnToGames < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :games, :ten_quotes_ids, :text
  end
end

class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :game_logs
  has_many :characters, through: :game_logs
  has_many :quotes, through: :characters

  serialize :ten_quotes_ids, Array

  def ten_quotes
    if ten_quotes_ids.length == 10
      quotes.where(id: ten_quotes_ids)
    else
      ten_quotes = quotes.order('RANDOM()').limit(10) # for MySQL use `quotes.order('RAND()').limit(10)`
      update ten_quotes_ids: ten_quotes.map(&:id)
      ten_quotes
    end
  end
end
```

Add a column of type `text` to your `Game` model called `ten_quotes_ids`. In your model, `serialize` the `ten_quotes_ids` column as an `Array`. This lets you store arrays of Ruby objects to the database. You could store *instances* of `quotes`, but they will not be kept in sync with your database if there are changes, so better to just store the `id`s so you can fetch the current records on demand.

In your `ten_quotes` method you're checking if `ten_quotes_ids` has 10 elements, and if so querying the `Game`'s `quotes` based on those `id`s and returning them, or else selecting a random set of 10 `quotes` belonging to the `Game` from the database, updating the `ten_quotes_ids` attribute, and returning the ten quotes.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for thank you. Learned that I can create attributes as arrays and store anything inside them. Appreciate the time you took to write this answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### edit 2

I removed my first idea, based your comment, as your information "a quote should belong to many samples" and "ten quotes were for a game that happened a week ago", my idea creating new model for samples with this relation as follow

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  # -> quotes -> samples
  has_many :quotes, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :quotes,   :allow_destroy => :true  
  has_many :samples, through: :quotes
end

class Quote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :game
  has_many :samples, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :samples,   :allow_destroy => :true 

end

class Sample < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :quote

  scope :just_last_week, lambda { where('created_at >= ?', 1.week.ago)}
end
```

I add accepts_nested_attributes_for  and allow_destroy to make easier you create child record from parent
here is [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) in case you want to know more

from game controller

```
# if you want get samples and 
  # for specific game
  @game = Games.find(params[:id])
  @samples = @game.samples.limit(10) # this will get 10 samples from samples
  @samples = @game.samples.just_last_week.limit(10) # this will get 10 samples created last week
  # for samples that created last week no matter what game is
  @samples = Sample.all.just_last_week
```

Comment: With this method would you be able to access the game in the database and see what the sample was? For example, I want to see what the ten quotes were for a game that happened a week ago.